# Task Scheduler executes script but does not output to log file

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am running into the following issue :

I have a task scheduler job running across a number of Azure VMs, it is scheduled to run at ~11pm every wednesday.

From what I can see the script executes the required change, however it does not generate the log output file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WlAC.png)

the argument I use is the following:

> -F C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scripts\automatexml_weu.ps1 -Verbose >  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scripts\xml_script_logs\xml_script_output_$(Get-Date
> -format "yyyyMMdd").log

But the log file is never generated.

If I run the above command outside of Task Scheduler it works with no issues

Anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Edit: it appears there is a workaround for this, take a look @Peyre answer

---

Unfortunately it doesnt seem possible to do it this way through Task Scheduler.

*"The scheduled task cannot redirect that way.  You will have to redirect to a file inside of the PowerShell script.  It is PowerShell that supports that redirection."* - [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/985ce84c-ac55-4fe8-b652-259d5373f747/redirect-script-output-to-file-in-task-scheduler?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: It works with "powershell -command" (the default), not "powershell -file"

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but it may help others. Redirecting powershell output in task scheduler is a bit tricky.

If you pass the script using the `-file` parameter, the redirection is always handled by the task scheduler CLI which has absolutely no idea of what `$(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd")` means and tries (unsuccessfully) to interpret it as a filename. More, as `$(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd")` contains space chars, the CLI splits it into multiples parameters adding more mess to the command line. If you do want to use `-file`, you have to rebuild the date from `%date%`

On the other hand, if you replace `-file` by `-command` and quote `>` with `^` to hide it from the task scheduler CLI, the redirection is handled by `powershell` which understands `$(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd")`. Be aware the the task scheduler CLI interprets `"` in the same way that `CMD` does so it will remove them. In that very case, it's not a problem as the `-f` of `Get-Date` is waiting for a `[String]` argument but if for instance, you use `$((get-date).tostring("yyyyMMdd"))`, you will get an error. So just replace `"` by `'` (eg. `$((get-date).tostring('yyyyMMdd'))`)

To summarize, your parameters should read

```
-command C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scripts\automatexml_weu.ps1 -Verbose ^> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scripts\xml_script_logs\xml_script_output_$(Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd').log
```

One last point, if you only redirect stream 1, you'll only get what your script sent to the output stream and will never get the content of the error/ warning/ verbose/ streams. If you are interested in them (I suppose you are as you have `-verbose` in you command), juste replace `^>` by `^*^>` in the command parameters.

```
-command C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scripts\automatexml_weu.ps1 -Verbose ^*^> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scripts\xml_script_logs\xml_script_output_$(Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd').log
```